# Data validation using Parsley is not working

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to use Parsley.js for validate some form fields. After read the docs and see how I should use it I follow the next steps:

- Add the attribute `data-validate` to form `<form action="" id="product_create" method="post" data-validate="parsley">`
- Add the extra attributes to form fields `<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product[price]" data-trigger="change keyup keypress" data-required="true" data-type="number">`

If I don't understand bad so when I change the value of `#product_price` error should appears right? Well it doesn't and I can't find why or how I'm doing wrong, any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the issue is that you've entered some invalid value and expected parsley to come up with an error-msg when you left the field?

I'm currently struggling with that, too - and it seems to be that way "by design": https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/262
Also the "classy demo" on http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html does not validate when you immediately enter invalid data, it only does so when you try to send the form.

Anyway, I have opened an issue on https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/385 and hope to understand the problem a bit better and maybe even get that changed ;-)

Comment: BTW, you may want to add `data-trigger="blur"` to handle the case that iser leaves field w/o input...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with data-validation-minlength="0"

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error came from setting one of my input values to value='',  which I know many people use. I found a workaround from that and it worked as it should.